# How to include external files in Python wheel?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm working on a Python package (built as a wheel), which requires some external files – i.e. ones that aren't in my package/repository. At runtime, it currently gets the path to these from a config file.

I'd like to instead bundle these files inside the wheel itself, so the package is all you need to install. Normally you'd use `package_data` to do this kind of thing, but I don't think that works for files [outside of the package tree](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html). I've wondered about making a build script, which first copies these into a local temporary directory. Would that work, or is there a more elegant way to do this?